# imagen de fondo en las opciones de un SELECT

Tags: html

quiero poner imagenes en las opciones de un SELECT.

```
<select id="listafotos" name="listafotos" style="text-align:right;width:100%"  >

  <option style="background-image:url(fotosobras/badge.png)" value="0">Seleccione imagen</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(fotosobras/imagen1.png)" value="1">imagen1</option>
      
 </select>
```

Solo me muestra el texto...
las imagenes estan el el root, carpeta 'listafotos'
pero no muestra las imagenes...
donde está el error...no lo veo...

Comment: Si no mal recuerdo de forma nativa, ningun navegador soporta eso, si deseas podrias intentar con alguna libreria como selectable, de jquery.